# How to find certain strings in List<string> via LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have this `List<string>`.

**How to get certain strings via LINQ?**

I guessed it should be like

```
List<string> test = new List<string>;

test.Add("1");

test.Add("2");

test.Add("1");


var dist = test.Where(s=>s  ==  "1") or ???
```

or

```
var dist = test.Distinct(a => a == "1"); ???
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to google for example the title of your question ?

Comment: This is so obviously googlable.

Comment: Give me time to edit questions guys!

Comment: What do you expect to have in the `dist` variable in your sample?

Comment: @nemesv I just need to find all distinct strings in List<string> via LINQ.

Comment: Off topic but... It's funny when people say to Google the question, cause usually when I google programming questions it brings me to SO. So.. If it's not already answered in SO.. Why not just answer it and make it a little easier for people in the future to find the correct answer. Who knows it might even bring new talented programmers to SO through increased visibility. Just a thought.

Comment: @TheFuzzyGiggler Yeah! I just need to know how to use LINQ for the simple List<string> to get all distinct values...

Comment: @TheFuzzyGiggler You'll just hit the MSDN page for the `Distinct` method querying google.  I don't see any need for anything beyond that.

Comment: @TheFuzzyGiggler: I basically agree in fact I rarely say to someone "google it". However, in this case the answer is inside the title itself. Infact, if you google the title, one of the first link is MSDN IEnumerable.Distinct page...

Comment: @Servy I'm not saying that some questions aren't very obviously googleable, it's just some people don't understand it from other sources and need extra clarification. Maybe they should state that in the question too? As a side note, I think every tutorial written by Microsoft is a horrible cryptic mess. I think they make things as difficult as possible on purpose for some reason. Could just be me... Not trying to cause any arguments though. Just like multiple options and easy access to information.

Comment: @TheFuzzyGiggler While your statements are often true, they are not true in this specific instance.  The MSDN page for `Distinct` in particular, is not bad at all, and clearly answers the question.

Comment: Peretz please just tell us what you expect the `dist` variable in your sample to contain.  It's the easiest way for us to figure out what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer guys! Thanks for many ------ :)

So it should be

```
var dist = test.Where(a => a == "1");
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436) method:

```
var dist = test.Distinct();
```

There is also an overloaded version of `Distinct` method which allows to pass custom comparer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this if you want to find out which strings are only in the list once:

```
List<string> test = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "1" };
var distinctStrings = test.GroupBy(s => s).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Key);
foreach (string str in distinctStrings)
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: That wasn't the question though; the question was to get all distinct strings.

Comment: Oh, and rather than `g.Count() == 1` you can use `g.Skip(1).Any()` so you don't need to iterate the whole thing.

Comment: But maybe the OP wants to know which ARE distinct. Not make a distinct list of the existing strings. Are you REALLY sure that wasn't the question?

Comment: @Servy If you look at the title, the OP wants to "find" distinct strings, not make the list distinct.

Comment: @itsme86 Yes, and the `Distinct` method returns a sequence of all of the distinct strings, rather than modifying the list to remove all non-distinct values, thus you are "finding all of the distinct strings".

Comment: @Servy No, it doesn't. .Distinct() would have the collection { "1", "2" }, where as my query would just contain { "2" }.

Comment: @itsme86 I didn't say `Distinct` would return the same results as your query, I said that `Distinct` would solve the OP's question as asked.